# How to add component into another Component in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-providers

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ig6pw.png) Here is the structure of the code.  I am trying to add video player component into my course component.
 Then I get exception.

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[VideoPlayerComponent -> Modal$$1]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[VideoPlayerComponent -> Modal$$1]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Modal$$1!
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[VideoPlayerComponent -> Modal$$1]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[VideoPlayerComponent -> Modal$$1]:

Comment: show the data from VideoPlayerComponent

Comment: you took StaticInjectorError(AppModule) it means u have missing to add your component to appmodule. Did u add your video component to appmodule imports?

Comment: Yes. I added that